# How to setup Geb 2.0 in IntelliJ (run/debug configurations)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, geb

I'm using Geb 2.0 (http://gebish.org/) and have downloaded the Gradle sample (https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle).

All works just fine on my machine with all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, ChromeHeadless).

I have imported the project in IntelliJ (latest Ultimate edition) and all normal code editing functions are working fine.

What fails is attempting to run a spec. I get an exception with the helpful hint of `the path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property`.

However, I can't figure out what to point it at. I've tried pointing at the `selenium-chrome-driver-3.6.0.jar` but that results in failure also.

I'm using `-Dgeb.env=chrome` and `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=SOMERANDOMEPATHSHERE`

Help?

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle example Geb project is set up to generate the appropriately configured IntelliJ project capable fo running the specs from the IDE. Simply run `./gradlew idea` and load the project by opening the `geb-example-gradle.ipr` file in IntelliJ instead of loading the project by importing it's Gradle build the way you do.